# Can you tell me specific what this program is doing?

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax, realloc

```
#include stdio.h
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CAPACITY_INCREMENT 6
double average(double data[], int count)
  {
   double sum = 0.0;
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<count;sum+=data[i++]);
   return sum/count;
  }

int main(void)
  {
    double *data = NULL;
    double *temp = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int capacity = 0;
    char answer = 'n';

   do
    {
      if(count == capacity)
       {
          capacity += CAPACITY_INCREMENT;
          if(!(temp = (double*)realloc(data, capacity*sizeof(double))))
         {
            printf("Error allocating memory for data values.\n");
            exit(1);
         }
         data = temp;
       }

       printf("Enter a data value: ");
       scanf(" %lf", data + count++);
       printf("Do you want to enter another (y or n)? ");
       scanf(" %c", &answer, sizeof(answer));
     } while(tolower(answer) != 'n');

    printf("\nThe  average of the values you entered is %10.2lf\n", average(data, count));
    free(data);
    return 0;
   }
```

I am a beginner in C and one of my friend who is helping me sent me this code, I understood that is printing the average of given number but I don't know what some syntaxes are doing like:

```
  if(!(temp = (double*)realloc(data, capacity*sizeof(double))))"
```

Can you explain how this is working step by step?

Comment: `scanf(" %lf", data + count++);`??? what is this? can you ever be more confusing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no "explain my code" site.

Comment: Why did you not simply call/email your friend and ask?

Comment: Because he doesn't know how to explain it. I'm sorry for any inconvenience, I just needed some help with it. It's not my code. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,  this line

```
 if(!(temp = (double*)realloc(data, capacity*sizeof(double))))
```

should look like

```
 if(!(temp = realloc(data, capacity*sizeof(double))))
```

because [as per this discussion we need not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

That said, to break down the statement,

1. First, `temp = realloc(data, capacity*sizeof(double))` gets evaluated. This statement reallocates `data` to have a memory allocated equal to the size of `capacity*sizeof(double)` bytes. The returned pointer is stored to `temp`.
2. Then essentially the whole statement reduces to `if (! (temp))`. This check for the success of the `realloc()` call by checking the returned pointer against NULL.

   - If `realloc()` failed, it returned NULL, and the `if` will evaluate to TRUE, so the program will execute `exit(1);` and get over.
   - If `realloc()` is a success, `temp` will have a non-NULL pointer, thereby, the `if` check will fail and the program will continue normally.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. Now I understand it.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).